# A printer is not removable and new cannot be installed, how to reset the "Devices and Printers" area?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, printer

Summary: I changed printers but cannot install the new one because the old one is stuck and blocks further installs.

I had a Samsung printer which I changed to a Brother one. I could delete the WiFi installation of the Samsung printer (as seen in the "Printers and Devices" page) but the USB one, grayed out, does not want to be uninstalled. When choosing "Remove device" nothing happens, it is still there.

I tried everything I could find on Internet:

- deleting the contents of `c:\Windows\system32\spool`
- deleting registry keys which mention the dribver or the printer
- `printui.exe /s /t2` and removing the driver

I very, very much suspect that this are got somehow corrupted as I cannot install my new printer.

What happens is that I go though the installation (manual, pointing out the WSD port) and **a test page** (part of the install process) **prints fine**. I also see it in Device Manager, under "Print queues".

I can also scan from the printer via a program such as FastStone (or other scanning software).

So the printer is "installed" but cannot make its way to the "Devices and Printers" page. It is visible to other programs (Word, Chrome print, ...) so that would not be such a nuisance, except that I cannot configure it (because this is done via the printer visible in Printers and Devices, when choosing the Properties of a printer).

Is there a way to clean/reset the Printers area of "Devices and Printers" so that a new printer is visible there?

Comment: See this page...https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/101274-uninstall-printer-driver-windows-10-a.html

Comment: @Moab thznks but I tried it all. The driver is not present anymore (or at l'est not visible in any of these places), the problem is with the ghost printer (which apparently preventd others to appear despite being installed)

Comment: Try this.... type in `printmanagement.msc` from run and then press Enter. From this GUI navigate to **All Drivers** and then **Remove driver package** from those options and also check the **All Printers** and then **Remove** those from there too. If or once all of the applicable driver packages and printers are removed, reboot your PC. Now check `printmanagement.msc` again and confirm the driver packages and printers are removed and if not do it again and reboot again and then check again and repeat again if needed. Once you reboot and confirm afterwards all are removed, THEN install printer.

Comment: Actually, be sure all printers USB connections are disconnected before you do all that but easy enough to try to simply rule out as a potential solution just in case. Maybe you will get lucky!!

Comment: Any update on anything with this problem you got here? I left some advice so did it help you any or what?